# Smallness of the category of schemes of finite type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, motivic-homotopy

Most sources about motivic homotopy theory mention that the category of (smooth) separated schemes of finite type over a (Noetherian of finite Krull dimension) base $S$ is essentially small, which is essential for the homotopy theory of its simplicial sheaves. Yet, none of the sources I came across proves or references that this category is not small, or indicates the small category that it is equivalent to. <strike>I guess the latter should be the category of (smooth) finitely generated algebras over $\Gamma(S,\mathcal{O}_S)$.</strike>

I would like to ask for a reference where such a statement is proven, preferably in more generality, if it exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can prove essential smallness of the category of finite type $S$-schemes (without further assumptions), where $S$ is any scheme, as follows:

- If $S$ is affine and we only consider affine finite type $S$-schemes, these correspond to finite type $\Gamma(S)$-algebras. These are isomorphic to algebras of the form $\Gamma(S)[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/I$ for some natural number $n$ and some ideal $I$. These algebras form a set.
- If $S$ is affine and we allow separated finite type $S$-schemes, these may be glued from affine finite type $S$-schemes $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and isomorphisms between the affine schemes $X_i \cap X_j \subseteq X_i$ and $X_j \cap X_i \subseteq X_j$. By the affine case, we can classify them by a set.
- If $S$ is affine and we allow arbitrary finite type $S$-schemes, these may be glued from finitely many affine finite type $S$-schemes $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and isomorphisms between the separated schemes $X_i \cap X_j \subseteq X_i$ and $X_j \cap X_i \subseteq X_j$. By the first two cases, we can classify them by a set.
- If $S$ is arbitrary, then finite type $S$-schemes may be glued from finite type $U$-schemes $X_U$, where $U$ runs through all open affines $U \subseteq S$, together with isomorphisms $X_U \times_U V \cong X_V$ for $V \subseteq U$. By the affine case, we may classify them by a set.

Remark that the category of locally finite type $S$-schemes is only essentially small when $S=\emptyset$: Consider $\coprod_{i \in I} S$ for sets $I$.

As Qiaochu points out, the category of (finite type) $S$-schemes is never small because it contains, for every set $X$, the scheme $(\emptyset,\mathcal{O})$ with the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}(\emptyset)=(\{X\},+,\cdot)$.

Comment: This is not the question being asked.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: It answers the following part: "Yet, non of the sources I came across [..] indicates the small category that is equivalent to." Or rather, since I don't know a reference, I just proved it here.

Comment: @HeinrichD: Thank you, I guess the third case is meant to be "...these may be glued from finitely many **separated** affine...".

Comment: @user24453: No. Affine schemes are separated. I use the second case for the intersections.

Comment: Very nice answer. Just a remark to the second-to-last paragraph: The category of *affine* $S$-schemes which are locally of finite type over $S$ *is* essentially small. This is good to know, since by Grothendieck's comparison lemma the category of Zariski sheaves over $\mathrm{Sch}/S$ is equivalent to the category of Zariski sheaves over $\mathrm{Aff}/S$ (both with the same finiteness condition). The latter is a honest category in that -- since $\mathrm{Aff}/S$ (with the finiteness condition) is essentially small -- you don't have any set-theoretical issues with constructing it.

Answer (score 7):

Asking about smallness instead of essential smallness is a distraction; smallness is not [invariant under equivalence of categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence), so the answer potentially depends delicately on how you construct the category of schemes (e.g. as locally ringed spaces or as functors of points).

It's also a distraction in the sense that it almost never holds. The affine case already exhibits the relevant phenomenon so let me stick to it. The category of finitely generated algebras over a base ring $R$ is essentially small, but it is never small for dumb reasons: an algebra is in particular a *set* equipped with some extra data, and the set part alone can already vary over a proper class. This phenomenon is ubiquitous whenever discussing categories of sets with extra structure. For example, there are a proper class's worth of zero ring, because $\{ X \}$ is a set with one element for every set $X$, and so we can put the zero ring structure on it.

Given an essentially small category you can construct a small category it's equivalent to by finding a [skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(category_theory)) of it.

Comment: The principle of equivalence even shows that "there is only one empty set" is not a reasonable statement. In fact, although being true in ZF, it fails in structural set theories such ETCS, and the type system of SEAR even forbids equating two sets.